# Как сделать паузу в Task(c#)?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть Task, который запускается при нажатие кнопки. В нем не используются бесконечные циклы.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => data.StartForFind(cancellationTokenSource.Token, textBoxStatus, treeViewResult), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Мне необходимо чтобы, при нажатии другой кнопки, задача останавливалась, а затем, при повторном нажатии, продолжала работать с того места, где она остановилась.

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Таски тут вообще не при чем, вам придется самому продумать как поставить ваш код на паузу. Это очень сильно зависит от того, что ваш код вообще делает и зачем его останавливать.

Comment: Используйте locker"ы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если управлять нужно неким циклом, то можно так

```
private ManualResetEvent _manualEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

private void Run()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while(условие остановки)
        {
            _manualEvent.WaitOne();
            // операции
        }
    });
}

private void Resume()
{
    _manualEvent.Set();
}

private void Pause()
{
    _manualEvent.Reset();
}
```

Comment: Прямо мысли читаете, как раз тоже о нем (`ManualResetEvent`) подумал :)

Comment: @yolosora циклы не используются. Задача запускает поиск файла. У меня есть требование чтобы поиск можно было приостановить, а затем продолжить

Comment: @Rumeet а как вы ищете файлы? У вас там в любом случае циклы / рекурсия / и то и другое

Comment: @yolosora через рекурсию. Рекурсия пробегается по всем папкам и потом для каждого каталога в обратном порядке вызывает метод поиска по имени файла. Этот метод вызывает еще один метод, который ищет содержание текста, если файл по названию найден

Comment: @Rumeet ну либо используйте `_manualEvent` в рекурсивной функции, либо вы можете переделать рекурсию в цикл и в цикле также юзать `_manualEvent`

Answer (score 3):

Останавливать поток надолго, хоть с помощью `while`, хоть с помощью `ResetEvent` - довольно расточительно: поток (ресурс операционной системы) занят, но не делает полезной работы.

Правильней было бы запоминать текущее состояние выполненной работы при включении паузы и завершать задачу (Task). А при продолжении восстанавливать состояние: стартовать новую задачу.

У вас осуществляется поиск файла. При включении паузы запоминаем номер (индекс) файла (или его имя). При продолжении начинаем просмотр коллекции файлов с него.